# MySQL Query using WHERE AND NOT

Tags: php, mysql

Simple question..

Is the below correct syntax?

```
  $mysqli->query("UPDATE details SET MemberStatus='Inactive' WHERE (MembershipType NOT LIKE '%Holiday%') AND (DateValidTo < '".$statusDate."')");
```

Comment: Yes its correct... And you can also remove these )

Comment: Thx Sunil for your time...  Never used NOT LIKE and AND before in the same code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct.

You can use tools like http://sqlfiddle.com/ to validate and test your queries on different versions or even different rdbms if you just want to try something out.

Also it is perfect to deliver sampledata if you have a probem with your queries, as the helpers don't have to retype your table schema by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct but you can write it below format also:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE details SET MemberStatus='Inactive' WHERE MembershipType NOT LIKE '%Holiday%' AND DateValidTo < '".$statusDate."'");
```